# How to Implements Dead Lock Example in Java

Tags: java, deadlock

I'm reading about [Java Deadlock](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/what-is-deadlock-in-java-how-to-fix-it.html) Situations, I have understood about where deadlock can occur, But I'm facing problem how I can implement the below example.

```
public class DeadLockDemo {

    public void method1() {
        synchronized (String.class) {
            System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");

            synchronized (Integer.class) {
                System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");
            }
        }
    }

    public void method2() {
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
            System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");

            synchronized (String.class) {
                System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried but no deadlock situation.

```
public class DeadLockDemo {
    public void method1() {
        synchronized (String.class) {
                System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");
            synchronized (Integer.class) {
                System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");
            }
        }
    }
    public void method2() {
        synchronized (Integer.class) {
                System.out.println("Aquired lock on Integer.class object");
            synchronized (String.class) {
                System.out.println("Aquired lock on String.class object");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        DeadLockDemo obj=new DeadLockDemo();
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {  
          public void run() { obj.method1(); }  
        };  
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {  
          public void run() {  obj.method2(); }  
        };  
        t1.start();  
        t2.start();  
      }  
}
```

How I can correct my above example to get Deadlock situation?

Comment: I'm confused: what works as expected, what doesn't work as expected, what does it do instead?

Comment: Why can't you just replace `final String resource1 = "..."` with `final Class<String> stringClass = String.class` etc?

Comment: Make 2 threads, one will call `method1()` in `run()` method and another will call `method2()` in `run()` method at the same time. But it will not always result in deadlock.

Comment: @NamanGala I already tried but didn't worked. I want exact deadlock as in my 2nd example.

Comment: You can force it to deadlock if you pass in something like a pair of CountdownLatches, and decrement/await them before each of the synchronized blocks.

Comment: @AndyTurner I updated my question and paste code that I tried. Please check now.

Comment: That exact code results in a deadlock for me! If it doesn't for you add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in method1 and method2 directly after you printed that you aquired the first locks. Also the `DeadLockDemo obj = new DeadLockDemo();` must be declared as final!

Comment: @Parker_Halo great It works. Now I just want to ask. Deadlock appears just because Integer & String extends the Object class? that is the reason of same resources?

Comment: @UnKnown Not really, the deadlock appears because Thread 1 locks on String.class and Thread2 locks on Integer.class. After that Thread1 trys to lock Integer.class which is already locked by Thread2 and vice versa

Comment: @Parker_Halo Ok Understood, it's mean 2 thread tries to lock same resources at same time? is it? just to confirm.

Comment: @Parker_Halo why you suggest me to declare `DeadLockDemo` obj as final? I'm not locking on this object.

Comment: You need to make it final to reference it in the inner class, that's why I edited it.

Comment: @AndyTurner nice.. you mean due to obj.method1(); and obj.method2();  and obj goes to inner synchronized block in both method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your example, is that one of the threads is going to grab both of the locks before the other one gets a chance to run<sup>1</sup>.  It will then release them and exit, and the second thread will be able to grab the locks; i.e. no deadlock.

If you changed the two methods to do this:

1. grab one lock
2. sleep for a bit (e.g. a second or so)
3. grab the other lock

and if they grab the locks in the opposite order to each other, then you should observe a deadlock.  (Possibly even calling `yield` instead of `sleep` would do it ... though the behavior will be less predictable than if you sleep.)

A deadlock can only occur when the lock acquisitions by the respective threads overlap in time.  That's why deadlocks have a tendency to slip past testing.

---

<sup>1 - The Java specs don't actually require this.  However the chances that the thread scheduler will deschedule / reschedule the threads in the way that will allow deadlock ... without some "help" in the form of a `sleep` ... are minuscule to zero.</sup>

Comment: Exactly! That's the easiest way of (almost) always getting a deadlock!

Comment: @AndyTurner now my edited code works, can I edit this answer to add my working code?

Comment: @UnKnown - feel free.  (But I think it is OK as it stands ...)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't guaranteed to get a deadlock because you don't know when the threads will be scheduled: thread 1 might have finished before thread 2 has even started.  (You can simulate this by adding a short sleep to the start of one of the threads.)

You can force the deadlock by using a CountDownLatch to ensure that the thread waits for the other to acquire the first resource:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

Thread t1 = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    synchronized (resource1) {
      latch.countDown();
      latch.await(); // InterruptedException omitted.

      synchronized (resource2) {}
    }
  }
};

Thread t2 = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    synchronized (resource2) {
      latch.countDown();
      latch.await(); // InterruptedException omitted.

      synchronized (resource1) {}
    }
  }
};

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a *possible* deadlock - you will only get it under specific circumstances. If you don't want to change your code as suggested in the other answer, you can also use a debugger to get into the deadlock.

1. Set breakpoints on `method1` and `method2`
2. Run debug. Your two threads should have been paused an waiting at those breakpoints (Where you see the threads depends on your IDE/Debugger, in Eclipse you see the list of threads in the upper left corner and can switch between threads by clicking on them)
3. Advance thread 1 a step to get into the `synchronized (String.class)` block
4. Advance thread 2 a step to get into the `synchronized (Integer.class)` block
5. At this point the deadlock is inevitable. If you continue both threads you should see the expected results.